# Present perfect vs past simple complex example

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

I have come across this question and locked up the internet for the answer but it is so complex to do such thing

The students ______ (go) to America a few years ago. No one of them has completed his studies yet, but we expect them to return in the coming few years.

A- have gone
B- went

My answer was A, I know the time is mentioned but they haven’t returned yet so the action is still continuing to the future

Comment: HInt: when you see a "few years ago", "last  month", and other "period limiters" the verb is in the simple past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is **B**. The phrase '**have gone**', would imply that the conversation was happening at the **same time** as the students leaving for America, however the sentence contradicts this by saying that they went **a few years ago**. This is why '**went**' would be the correct answer, as it talks about the past tense, something that has **already happened**. You can see the definition of **past tense** here;

> In English, the **past tense** (or preterite) is one of the inflected forms of a verb. The past tense of regular verbs is made by adding -d or -ed to the base form of the verb, while those of irregular verbs are formed in various ways (such as see→saw, **go→went**, be→was/were).